# SQL Server and run asp page fails

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I have a page on the server and i tried to run it like this article:
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20010328.asp

then I get an error:

> Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. The step did not
>   generate any output.  The step failed.

When I try to edit the script I get another error:

> Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID
>   {AA40D1D6-CAEF-4A56-B9BB-D0D3DC976BA2} from the IClassFactory failed
>   due to the following error: c001f011.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS)

When I run the asp page manually it works fine! do you know what can be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would apply the most recent service pack for SQL Server both to your server and to the workstation(s) where you use Management Studio. The error you mentioned has been fixed: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/557402/ssms-can-no-longer-create-or-edit-job-steps

This will fix the problem when you edit the job step in Management Studio. There are some other workarounds (e.g. re-register some DLL, or restart Management Studio), but those are only temporary. You can also disable UAC, but you may have that feature enabled for a reason. The real fix is to apply service packs / cumulative updates to fix the underlying code.

As for the error message from the job, there could be a number of things going on. Who is the owner of the job? Who is the user executing the VBScript? What exactly is the job doing?

Comment: the owner is **sa**,
the user executing the vbscript i wanted to be the **sa** as well but by the error it seems to be the **NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE**
as for what the job is doing, just a active x of the WScript.Shell to run a page that check for expiration of products, change their status and send an email to the admin (all of it in one step in the asp page)

Comment: Why do you need an ASP page to read the database and send an e-mail? Why don't you configure database mail and do this all from a stored procedure in a SQL Agent job step? No web server, ASP page, VBScript, etc. required. You're making a simple task a lot more complicated by adding a ton of variables. IMHO.

Comment: I know its quirk! i will do it like you said at the end but for now i need this method to work as well

Comment: the main reason for using asp page is for aspemail with queueing and dynamicly sending the email to the recipients it should be sent via the session and stuff

Comment: so sql server is up to date... error is still the same, changed the user running the computer with administrative permissions and it worked... is it possible to have the **NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE** to run the service and not the user?

Comment: What do you mean "sql server is up to date"? What service pack/cumulative update did you apply to the server? Did you apply anything to the client where you're using Management Studio - that is what is giving you that error, right? I'm getting a little confused. What "service" are you talking about? What "recipients" are found "in the session and stuff"? What does SQL Server Agent have to do with this if you are calling an ASP page from a VBScript? There is no session in that case. So where are the recipients coming from?

Comment: I still am going to suggest that you will be WAY better off if you just do this right from the start. Turn on database mail instead of using aspemail, and send the recipients / message etc. to a stored procedure. I am trying to even get a diagram of what you are trying to do... is it a job that is calling a VBScript that is hitting an ASP page to send an e-mail? It is *screaming* over-engineered.

Comment: sql server sp1, both on server and client (same machine)
the page i'm running from the agent has a connection to the db and with several include files to the emails list of possible recipients. the select statment is then looking at all the products the are expired and hide them, at the same time sends an email to the set of email it should.
in addition when using aspemail i can have queueing and with database mail i can't, what about database mail and unicode like hebrew in the email?

Comment: Still sounds like you are relying on data in text files on the file system - why? Isn't this why you're using a database? Database mail is based on service broker, so is based on queueing by definition. It also should have no problem with Unicode data - problems there would most likely originate on the receiving end.